# JavaScript undefined variable in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

This code is supposed to switch the display property of all children elements of #slide-container to "block" with time delay two seconds between the switches.

```
var magic = window.setInterval(function(){
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            var children = document.getElementById('slide-container').children;
            for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    children[i].style.display = "block";
                    console.log(i);
                },2000);
            }
            magic = window.clearInterval(magic);
        } else {
            console.log("...");
        }
}, 1000);
```

I am using it along with this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="slide-container">
            <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8qBcyzc.jpg"></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/oxMTFTF.png"></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JTM6Yqg.jpg"></li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

It says it cannot find children or children[0]. But that variable has been specified and the dom nodes exist.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure issue.
Try adding a 3rd parameter to the setTimeout (doesn't work):

```
setTimeout(function(i){
   children[i].style.display = "block";
   console.log(i);
}, 2000, i);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/9qaXE/)

Another formate:

```
    var i = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        children[i].style.display = "block";
        i++;
        if (i == children.length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 2000);
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/MS8mR/)

ES6 is around the corner, the `let` statement is especially built for situations like this:

```
for (let i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      children[i].style.display = "block";
      console.log(i);
   }, 2000);
}
```

However this is not the answer you need for right now. This was just a note.

Comment: The images are shown but all at once. The point is that there is 2 seconds delay for the next image to appear.

Comment: Yeah, iv'e been looking forward to that

Comment: @Johnny Oh yes, sorry.

Comment: @Johnny Check out the edit. I suggest just using a setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Try encasing the setTimeout in an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression)

```
 for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++) {
      (function (index) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    children[index].style.display = "block";
                    console.log(i);
                }, 2000);
            })(i);
        }
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CrRcm/1/)**

The reference of `i` is common to all the functions executed by `setTimeout` . So by the time the function inside executes , the value of `i` will point to `children.length` .

But there is no element that refers to `children[children.length]` which does not exist and throws an error.

Comment: The images are shown but all at once. The point is that there is 2 seconds delay for the next image to appear.

Answer (score 1):

By the time `setTimeout` is ready `i` will be the length of `children` so you have to capture the value of `i`

try this

```
var time = 2000;
for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {
    (function( child, time) {
       window.setTimeout(function() {
          child.style.display = "block";
       }, time);
    }( children[i], time));
    time += 2000;
}
```

or you could do this. ...  I have fixed the delay thing

```
var hideElement = function( element, time) {
   window.setTimeout(function() {
      element.style.display = 'block';
   }, time);
};

var time = 2000;
for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {
   hideElement(children[i], time);
   time += 2000;
}
```

Comment: The second example works perfectly. The first one trows error <code>Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined </code>. Nice idea with that hideElement function. BTW. Last example should be 'block' instead of 'none' ;]. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah with the first one it still has to be in the loop.

Comment: Now both are working! Good idea with the anonymous function, simple and effective.